# how to convert latitude,longitude (string) to coordinates

Tags: oracle, coordinates, spatial, oracle-spatial

I have a table (Address) with 3 fields (id, latitude, longitude) and other table (Polygons) with 2 fields (id, coordinates (type = mdsys.sdo_geometry)). my question is, how can I relate coordinates to know if the address is inside the polygon's area

**Address**

```
id ---------- 1   
latitude ---- 36.13948149   
longitude --- -86.84178303
```

**Polygons**

```
id ---------- 15
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003,1041002,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(13650333.621154,5324021.16148257,13650233.7612594,5324171.58351056,13650028.4381112))
```

Answer (score 0):

(Corrected my answer to match your question more closely)

A simple SELECT will do what you want:

```
select p.id, ...
from polygons p, address a
where a.id = 1
and sdo_contains (p.coordinates, sdo_geometry(2001,4326,sdo_point_type(a.longitude,a.latitude,null),null,null)) = 'TRUE';
```

This will return all the polygons from your table that contain your selected address point. Notice there is no need to transform the GPS coordinates to the coordinates of the polygon. That is done automatically.